# client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => { ^ ReferenceError: client is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to implement a code in my bot but it's giving this error when I run the index:
ReferenceError: client is not defined

My source:

```
const discordTranscripts = require('discord-html-transcripts');
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db')
const db = new QuickDB;
const Discord = require('discord.js');

        
        client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
           if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
              let choice = interaction.values[0]
              const member = interaction.member
              const guild = interaction.guild
```

I've tried many solutions! He's on V14! I will not post the whole code because the error is in this part

I did research to find a solution but none of them worked

Comment: Where did you define `client`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a client.

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [/*intentsArrayHere*/],
    partials: [/*partialIntentsArrayHere*/]
});
```